# Left margin in textfield for uiimage

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to put an image inside textfied using Xamarin iOS and images does appear ok but I can't figure out how to put margin on left side of image due to which it's stuck to the left edge of textfield. Below is the code and result. What am I missing here ?

```
 var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("xyz.png"))
        {
            Frame = new RectangleF(1,1,20,20);
        };
        Tf1.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
        Tf1.LeftView = imageView;
```

[image: Result of uiimage]

Comment: What happens if you change the X component of the imageView's frame?

Comment: Changing X component didn't have any effect which I had assumed that it would be like x,y coordinate but no :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following to get the indentation you are looking to achieve by creating another **UIView**, and placing the **UIImageView** within this existing **UIView** with an offset such as in the following example:-

```
var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("xyz.png"))
{
    // Indent it 10 pixels from the left.
    Frame = new RectangleF(10,0,20,20)
};

UIView objLeftView = new UIView(new Rectangle(0,0,30,20));
ojLeftView.AddSubview(imageView);
```

and then on the **UITextField** set the **LeftView** as such:-

```
objUITextField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
objUITextField.LeftView = objLeftView;
```

Comment: I had tried putting left indent but hadn't put a new SubView. I'll try that let know.

Comment: I had tried all sorts like yourself to try getting this to work, even using LeftViewRect and Frame and various other methods.  From what I can tell also when I was looking around there was many different answers, each with varying levels of success however from end-users that seem to also reflect that the OS version has some dependency on the approach used.  With at least this approach it does work on IOS 8.  If it doesn't work for you, just let me know your OS version and I will take another look.  I'm pretty sure this method will work however as its only a UIView we are displaying.

Comment: Great answer.  How can I do this for an image on the right side and provide a right margin?